# PROLOG sum of integers inside a list

Tags: list, prolog, sum

I have a list of functions

```
List = [segmentTime(red,a,c,2),segmentTime(green,c,e,3),segmentTime(green,e,h,4),segmentTime(blue,h,i,5)]
```

How do I find the sum of the integer part of the function of all elements in the list?

i.e

```
sum = 2+3+4+5
```

A snippet code of a predicate would be extremely useful.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You don't have a list of "functions". You have a list of "compound terms". Prolog has predicates, facts, and terms, but no functions.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have already tried to make this work? If you haven't then please try and then post the code.

Comment: Here's a clue: `sum([segmentTime(_,_,_,I)|Xs],R) :-`.

Answer (score 1):

You will be surprised how simple the answer is.

```
sumList([],0).
sumList([segmentTime(_,_,_,X)|T],Z):- sumList(T,Z1),Z is Z1+X.
```

**OUTPUT**

```
?-sumList([segmentTime(red,a,c,2),segmentTime(green,c,e,3),segmentTime(green,e,h,4),segmentTime(blue,h,i,5)],M).
M=14
```

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use **library(lambda)**.

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

getList(L):-
 L = [segmentTime(red,a,c,2),segmentTime(green,c,e,3),segmentTime(green,e,h,4),segmentTime(blue,h,i,5)].

sumOfList(L, S) :-
   foldl(\X^Y^Z^(X = segmentTime(_,_,_,V), Z is Y + V), L, 0, S).
```

Ouput :

```
?- getList(L), sumOfList(L, S).
L = [segmentTime(red, a, c, 2), segmentTime(green, c, e, 3), segmentTime(green, e, h, 4), segmentTime(blue, h, i, 5)],
S = 14.
```